# SQL agent job failed with an error 0x80131904

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, sql-agent-job

I have one SQL agent job that executing the SSIS package. When the job is running through schedule then it is giving an error:

> Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904. Server: XXXXX Package path: "XXXX" Environment reference Id: 2.  Description: The operation failed because the execution timed out.

But when I manually running the job by right clicking on it then the job runs successfully.

Could anyone help me on this to find out the root cause and solution of the issue.

Thank you so much in Advance!!

Comment: Paste all error text, sql agent dont give just this part. The problem will be that sql agent service user don't have rights...

Comment: Please check now....

Comment: This error is unfortunately meaningless; all it really tells you is that an Integration Services package failed. You'll need to turn on logging for Integration Services and then consult the `sysssislog` table (or other logging as configured in the package run).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that SQL Agent Service user don't have rights to execute package.

Two solutions:

1. Change SQL Server Agent service user
   [read where sql management studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-service-startup-account-sql-server-agent-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Make a proxy account for SQL Agent JOB Step [ssis proxy account](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/129293-configure-an-ssis-package-to-execute-as-a-proxy-account)

Go for the 2, because if You have more than one JOB or some policies.....